# Can I delete fighters?

Tags: let-it-die

After defeating Max, I unlocked Tier 2 fighters with a much higher level cap than 25. However, I only had one more free slot for a new fighter. The other 4 slots were occupied by level 25 fighters that can't level up any further.

Can I delete or remove these Tier 1 fighters somehow to make room for higher tier fighters? I don't recall seeing an option or button to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one fighter, store the one you want to delete in the freezer by switching to another character. You should have the option to remove them on the left menu once they are stored.

Comment: After checking, I can verify that this option is there. Not sure how I missed it before.. This is easier than going and getting my characters killed.

Answer (score 5):

Senpai!

To make room for a new fighter, you can either let one die in the Tower of Barbs, then select to dismiss them from the Freezer rather than recovering them, or you can just rack up more SPLithium to upgrade your Freezer space from the TDM menu!

Good luck out there, and don't give up climbing for the top!

Comment: Ah, I was hoping I wouldn't have to go get them killed first, but I guess I do. Thank you!

Comment: @Uncle Death Awesome name, and thank you for that info :D